# How to count number of records per second?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the folowing set of values in the field trace (timestamp without time zone) in a DB postgresql:

```
"2017-02-22 18:46:43.394"
"2017-02-22 18:46:43.316"
"2017-02-22 18:46:43.237"
"2017-02-22 18:46:42.011"
"2017-02-22 18:46:41.927"
"2017-02-22 18:46:41.728"
```

And I would like to get the AVG of the occurrences (COUNT) by second. In this example would be:

```
18:46:43 > 3 occurrences
18:46:42 > 1 occurrences
18:46:41 > 2 occurrences

AVERAGE = 2 occurrences per second
```

Proposal:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(trace???))
FROM log_data
```

Comment: do You need to do this only for one date or group by hours and ommit days ? In result we can see only hours without a days.

Comment: select ROUND(AVG(extract(Col FROM ts::time) )) from  table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show this code:

```
select
count(date_trunc('sec',exe.x)),
date_trunc('sec',exe.x)
from
(
    select
    unnest(
        array
        [
        '2017-02-22 18:46:43.394'::timestamp,
        '2017-02-22 18:46:43.316'::timestamp,
        '2017-02-22 18:46:43.237'::timestamp,
        '2017-02-22 18:46:42.011'::timestamp,
        '2017-02-22 18:46:41.927'::timestamp,
        '2017-02-22 18:46:41.728'::timestamp
        ]
    ) as x
) exe
group by date_trunc('sec',exe.x)
```

Comment: To be more preceise, I edited your query as follows:
    SELECT
    AVG(A) as average_queries
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT
     (count(date_trunc('sec',log_alarme.trace))) as A ,
     date_trunc('sec',log_alarme.trace)
     FROM log_alarme
     GROUP BY date_trunc('sec',log_alarme.trace)
    ) as A